How to publish if the other co-authors do not cooperate (a concern)
I am an ERC, postdoc, I have completed my work and try to publish.
I am afraid my co-authors, one of them is the PI, do not want to publish, due to lack of interest in their part and busy with their own projects (I see signs like lack of responses in their part).
I am the one who do most of the work, the other co-author helps me in the experimental design process (not the entire thing though, just part of it). The PI does not help a lot to be honest, but I thought fair enough as it is my project and I used the facility (PI's lab) though  with some difficulties as there are not much support.
I did some research that it seemed impossible to publish without the consent of the other authors. So, I am wondering if there is anything that I can do to publish my work if the co-authors do not cooperate?
I haven't submitted the paper yet and they haven't told me explicitly that they don't wanna publish. My concern is they are blocking the publication process either delaying or not wanting to publish it. I know I need to talk to them, it's not also easy to be in touch with them, as they are not that responsive to my email. So, I am wondering what should I do if they are blocking this publication process ?

You need the consent of all authors to publish with a reputable publisher. You seem to have two options.
The first is to convince them that what you have should be published. Then the problem goes away. You seem to be assuming too much about their willingness. Talk to them. You should, perhaps, start with the PI who may have valid concerns about publishing. But where you start is partly a question of personalities and, so, hard to give good advice from a distance.
The second option is to abandon the joint work and do something that doesn't require their authorship, though it might include their participation in lesser ways. In some fields that is pretty hard to do without the PI being an author and I think you may be in one of those fields. So you probably need to convince the PI even for this option. Good luck.

Thanks for the advice, I appreciate it. I know I am assuming. This is the worst scenario that I can think of; I hope this will not happened but would like to be prepared for this. This presupposition  is based on some experiences that I have with the PI. The other co-author is also ecr and actually pretty nice& more responsive before  (Im saying bfore bcs I hv sent email (more than a month & follow up emails & no responses). I corresponded with the PI  about other matters, but when I mentioned the manuscript, no rspnses. I told the PI that Im available to discuss but no responses (yet).
